# What is the greedy many-to-many alignment algorithm in this paper?

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching, alignment, string-matching

I got stuck by this greedy many-to-many alignment algorithm depicted below in [this paper](https://aclanthology.org/2020.acl-main.29.pdf#page=5):

[image]

I wonder how it works? I have googled but found nothing related.

Answer (score 0):

I found its video on [papertalk](https://papertalk.org/papertalks/6872), and got to know the mechanism. It's not a classic algorithm but just an alignment method utilized by the author.

It's actually very simple.

> Each ground truth segment first aligns to the maximally overlapping predicted segment

[image]

> each leftover predicted segment then aligns to the maximally overlapping ground truth segment

[image]

The goal of these two steps is to find a target for each predicted label. That is, disregarding the directions of the arrows, the connected ground truth segment label and predicted segment label are paired to do pooling and then calculate the loss.

In the paper the above mechanism is not used in the beginning, but the teacher forcing is used. In the beginning, the ground truth boundaries are directly utilized to do pooling and then loss.